# Is there any performance or difference in flutter(dart) in used inline callbacks vs declared functions?

Tags: flutter, dart

There are 2 ways to do something for example on button `onPressed`

1. Have inline function there, so you declare the function callback

```
IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // do something
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.share))
```

VS

2. you pass reference to one existing function declared elsewhere. Can be on the same scope or from another class object.method etc

```
IconButton(
                  onPressed: _onShareClicked,
                  tooltip: t.share,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.share))

void _onShareClicked() {
      // do something
}
```

My question is if there is any performance difference or pros vs cons of those approaches?

In some older programming languages and especially not compiled ones, method 2 was recommended so the function was not always redeclared on re-render and things like that.

Dart is a compiled language and I don't know exactly the internal workings therefore am asking here.

The way I am currently coding is:
I use method 2 when my function is long, has a lot of statements and don't want to "pollute" the markup with the logic

I do use approach 1 when my functions are small and also the build method is still readable and does not grow huge.

Comment: Both the approaches are fine. What you are doing right now is what I follow as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would change my approaches to method 2 only if there is some performance benefit, be it in re-render time, memory/cpu usage or something else. I know that using `const` whenever possible helps and this is why I ask what is the case with the functions